# removeClass then addClass with jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some code that looks like this:

```
$('aside a').removeClass('selected');
itemToSelect.addClass('selected');
```

The intention is to removed selected styling from a list of links and then apply it to the one for the link to the current page.

I suspect it works with jQuery, but jQueryUI seems to override these methods and I can't for the life of me figure out how to bend them so they work. I've tried putting the addClass into the complete function for removeClass but the behaviour of that wasn't what I wanted (swinging between not being called or being called multiple times).

Is there a way I can perhaps just call the standard jQuery methods (I need jQueryUI elsewhere).

Edit: If I set the duration on the removeClass to 0 and put the addClass in a setTimeout then I can set the timeout to 0 even and the behaviour works. Doesn't feel like the cleanest approach though but the behaviour is acceptable.

Comment: Visiting the [jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/) explicitly states that "jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library." So the answer is, probably, 'no.'

Comment: Are you sure that `itemToSelect` is valid after the first line has been executed?

Comment: @frnhr yes, if I wrap the addClass in a setTimeout(... , 500) it works. Obviously, it's a bit rubbish though.

Comment: in seems to work in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hZjw4/ or do i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

How about ..  removing  all classes to all the elements in your div, and THEN add SELECTED to the link that has been kicked.

```
$('div#menu a').click(function () {
       $("#div a").removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: How does that get around the problem of `removeClass()`/`addClass()` being methods of the jQuery library, and not jQuery UI? (Not to mention the inevitable *next* problem of creating *another* problem, given that `.click()` is, similarly, part of jQuery, and not jQuery UI.)

Comment: It doesn't. It's the same thing.